# How to remove something from a php code without destroying the syntax

Tags: php

I'd like to remove everything which has something to do with `fuehrerschein` How can I do this?

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO `versionierung`(`version`, `fuehrerschein`)
        VALUES(
            '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "',
            " .$fuehrerschein. "
            )";
```

Comment: I really don't get what you need help with... every text editor has a built in replace function

Comment: I'm a complete php noob, I just want to remove "fuererschein" from this code and don't know which )"'., I can delete

Comment: If you just remove the word fuehrerschein it will break your syntax. if thats fine with you just use the "find and replace" function of your text editor. If not then you have to explain to me more in detail what it is that you try to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO `versionierung`(`version`)
        VALUES('" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

most modern text editors has a function called "find and replace". Some editors even lets you replace all accourances of a word inside all documents of a given folder.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pay attention to each occurrence of fuehrerschein.

Follow these steps:

1- find all occurrences of  fuehrerschein
2- check the code around it
3- create find-and-replace list

for example, from the above sql statement :
$sql = "REPLACE INTO `versionierung` (`version`, `fuehrerschein`)
        VALUES('" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "', " .$fuehrerschein. ")";

**find:** , `fuehrerschein`
**replace with:** ''

**find:**   "'," .$fuehrerschein 
**replace with:** "'"

good luck